# Is Google Native Client (NaCl) vulnerable to Meltdown or Spectre attacks?

Tags: exploit, google-nativeclient, spectre

I run `sel_ldr_x86_32 file32.nacl` and `sel_ldr_x86_64 file64.nacl` on my Intel machine vulnerable to [Meltdown and Spectre](https://meltdownattack.com/).

Given that even [JavaScript can employ Spectre](https://spectreattack.com/spectre.pdf), I am curious if NaCl'ed binaries can. Are there any known vulnerabilities of NaCl related to Meltdown or Spectre? Does NaCl provide enough powers to binaries to run Meltdown or Spectre? Examples of such vulnerabilities would be escaping the NaCl sandbox or reading something from any memory otherwise unavailable for the application.